# pandas-highcharts でグラフが描画されない

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, highcharts

#### 実現したいこと

取得した株価データを pandas-highcharts を使って jupyter notebook でグラフを描画したいです。実行したところ何も表示されないどころかエラーも表示されず困っています。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
from pandas_highcharts.display import display_charts
df = ... # ここでDateFrame型のデータを作りました
display_charts(df,chart_type='stock')
```

#### 試したこと

notebook のブラウザを変えてもうまくいきませんでした。
pandas-highcharts について調べてもよくわかりませんでした。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

notebook==6.0.3
pandas==0.24.2
pandas-highcharts==0.5.2

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/244001

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Python Pandas からお手軽に highcharts が使える kanichart 作りました。](http://fx-kirin.com/python/kanichart/), [python-highcharts と pandas-highcharts を使って Jupyter Notebook にローソク足を表示してみました](https://va2577.github.io/post/168/), [Python pandas のデータを Highcharts/Highstock + Jupyter でプロットしたい](http://sinhrks.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/06/13/195344)

Comment: @Kitchen さん、私の環境だと、Jupyter Notebook を起動して最初に実行された `display_charts` はグラフは描画され、2回目以降は描画されない（空のセルになる）という状態になりました。Kitchen さんの環境だとどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

JupyterLabを使ってみてはどうですか？
jupyter notebookの進化版みたいですよ。
私も同じでしたがJupyterLabを使ったら解決できました。
あとデータフレームはデータが大きすぎると表示できなかったので
データを絞り込むといいかもしれません。